# XUbuntu C++ Compiler Error Mutex is not a Member of std

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compiler-errors, virtualbox

Hallo I running with virtual box in windows xubunt.

I want to compile a library names vsomeip version 2.10.0 but i get the error:

mutex is not a member of std

Have anyone an Idea how i can fix this, I need this Library??

I use cmake.

Comment: Does your code include the `<mutex>` header? Are you compiling in C++11 mode? Does your compiler/standard library _support_ C++11?

Comment: This a library from a third person not my library. I compile it with cmake and then make

Comment: Fine. Does the file from "not my library" that is failing to compile include that header? Can you compile a file with just `#include <mutex>` correctly?

Comment: Yes I can compile a File with include mutex correctly and the file include mutex too

Comment: Please edit your question with the full error log produced by a verbose build (`make VERBOSE=1`)